# navigate relative to child route from my main routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

my app.routing forRoot() file :

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'immeuble', loadChildren: 'app/immeuble/immeuble.module#ImmeubleModule'},
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

In my feature module `ImmeubleModule` I have immeuble.routing forChild file

```
const IMMEUBLE_ROUTES: Routes = [

  { path: ':id', component: ImmeubleComponent, children: [
    { path: 'general', component:GeneralComponent  },
    { path: 'objet', component:GeneralComponent  },
    { path: '**', redirectTo:'general', pathMatch:'full' },
  ] },
  { path: '', component: ImmeubleComponent , pathMatch:'full',children:[
    { path: '', component:AccueilComponent  },
  ]},
];
```

My actual path is `immeuble/2/general`

With this path, I have two activated route:

1. root outlet in AppComponent (matched when `/immeuble`)
2. and as child of root outlet I have outlet in ImmeubleComponent (matched on `/2/general`)

I have all links inside my AppComponent, so I want add a link to navigate to `/immeuble/2/object` without specifying `/immeuble/2` I just want something like:

```
router.navigate(['object'], relativeTo: activatedRoute[ImmeubleComponent])
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can inject and use ActivatedRoute to query current route and child routes in order to navigate the actual route you want.

In your case, you can get children array with ActivatedRoute.children method, then look for the deepest one and use as param for navigate:

```
this.router.navigate(['./', {params}], { relativeTo: _.last(this.route.children) });
```

- In this example you can update params for current route, but also you can navigate to upper levels ('../') or other routes relative to current.
- Im asuming the last of children is the deepest one, but I haven't tested it. In my case, firstChild method from ActivatedRoute was enough :).